# Windows/Batch: Search Directory and Subfolders for file type and print to text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm working on a line of code in my batch file where it will scan a users profile and display all the .txt files stored within the profile.

Line in bold above the code are my comments upon what its doing.

This is what I have, but I keep getting an error that I can't figure out how to fix.

---

**(Scan PC's C:/Active_UserProfile) (Search any .txt)             (A:Below)**

```
cd /D C:\%USERPROFILE% DIR     *.txt /A /s /b    > %CD%\%INPUT%\Example.txt
```

**A:(create .txt in current working directory showing paths to .txt's)**

---

**Batch lines:**

```
echo "Scanning Directory: C:\%USERPROFILE%
echo "Terminal Destination:%CD%\%INPUT%"

cd /D C:\%USERPROFILE% DIR *.txt /A /s /b > %CD%\%INPUT%\Example.txt

echo "Scanning Directory: C:\%USERPROFILE%
echo "Terminal Destination:%CD%\%INPUT%"
```

---

**Output:**

```
"Scanning Directory: C:\Users\josep"
"Terminal Destination: M:\_TodaysRefresh\6"

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

"Scanning Directory: C:\Users\josep"
"Terminal Destination: M:\_TodaysRefresh\6"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting that this line `cd /D C:\%USERPROFILE% DIR *.txt /A /s /b > %CD%\%INPUT%\Example.txt` should be two lines split before the `DIR`.

Then I would have to tell you that it's just `%USERPROFILE%` not `C:\%USERPROFILE%`

Comment: Thank you for the input. i'll give it a shot. Just to make sure I should have the syntax like so?

cd /D %USERPROFILE% 
DIR *.txt /A /s /b > %CD%\%INPUT%\Example.txt